# Dropped packets in all Linux and Unix

Tags: linux, networking, unix, ethernet, packet-loss

I have a problem. I have motherboard by Supermicro – X11SBA-LN4F. There are 4 ethernet ports. In first port i have internet. In second port i have my local network. When, i write "ifconfig" or "netstat -i", i can see on my second interface (my local network) dropped packets. This count are incremented

```
em2       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:7b:91:3e
          inet addr:192.168.110.181  Bcast:192.168.110.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17441 errors:0 dropped:1380 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1226317 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

After my search from google, i found this:
https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7007165

```
Beginning with kernel 2.6.37, it has been changed the meaning of dropped packet count. Before, dropped packets was most likely due to an error. Now, the rx_dropped counter shows statistics for dropped frames because of:

Softnet backlog full  -- (Measured from /proc/net/softnet_stat)
Bad / Unintended VLAN tags
Unknown / Unregistered protocols
IPv6 frames when the server is not configured for IPv6

If any frames meet those conditions, they are dropped before the protocol stack and the rx_dropped counter is incremented.
```

First of all, i written this command:

```
tcpdump -vv -i em2
```

When i make this command, the count of dropped packets on my second interface are stopped. But, when i abort "tcpdump", the count of dropped packets are incremented again.

I disable IPv6 
 
I checked all VLANS. On that port i have only one Untag VLAN in local network 
I checked file /proc/net/softnet_stat. In that file i have info from only first column and that is good

```
00000013 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00002fbc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
000000f3 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0000268f 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

I analyzed by "tcpdump" all traffic. I have only – ARP Request, Broadcats and Rip. And it is not bad 
I enabled promiscuous mode, but that no help 
I checked cable and connectors 
I install last driver 
I increased ring caches size, but that no help 
And i checked all Unix and Linux: Zeroshell, Pfense, FreeBsd, Ubuntu Server (with native kernel & compiled by me), CentOS (with native kernel & compiled by me). All not help

```
ethtool -i em2

driver: igb
version: 5.3.4.4
firmware-version: 3.25, 0x800005d0
bus-info: 0000:06:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

All statistic on that interface:

```
ethtool -S em2

NIC statistics:
     rx_packets: 29675
     tx_packets: 0
     rx_bytes: 2208735
     tx_bytes: 0
     rx_broadcast: 29636
     tx_broadcast: 0
     rx_multicast: 39
     tx_multicast: 0
     multicast: 39
     collisions: 0
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_no_buffer_count: 0
     rx_missed_errors: 0
     tx_aborted_errors: 0
     tx_carrier_errors: 0
     tx_window_errors: 0
     tx_abort_late_coll: 0
     tx_deferred_ok: 0
     tx_single_coll_ok: 0
     tx_multi_coll_ok: 0
     tx_timeout_count: 0
     rx_long_length_errors: 0
     rx_short_length_errors: 0
     rx_align_errors: 0
     tx_tcp_seg_good: 0
     tx_tcp_seg_failed: 0
     rx_flow_control_xon: 0
     rx_flow_control_xoff: 0
     tx_flow_control_xon: 0
     tx_flow_control_xoff: 0
     rx_long_byte_count: 2208735
     tx_dma_out_of_sync: 0
     lro_aggregated: 0
     lro_flushed: 0
     tx_smbus: 0
     rx_smbus: 0
     dropped_smbus: 0
     os2bmc_rx_by_bmc: 0
     os2bmc_tx_by_bmc: 0
     os2bmc_tx_by_host: 0
     os2bmc_rx_by_host: 0
     tx_hwtstamp_timeouts: 0
     rx_hwtstamp_cleared: 0
     rx_errors: 0
     tx_errors: 0
     tx_dropped: 0
     rx_length_errors: 0
     rx_over_errors: 0
     rx_frame_errors: 0
     rx_fifo_errors: 0
     tx_fifo_errors: 0
     tx_heartbeat_errors: 0
     tx_queue_0_packets: 0
     tx_queue_0_bytes: 0
     tx_queue_0_restart: 0
     rx_queue_0_packets: 29675
     rx_queue_0_bytes: 2090035
     rx_queue_0_drops: 0
     rx_queue_0_csum_err: 0
     rx_queue_0_alloc_failed: 0
```

Where i have error ? Please help me. And thanks for you attention.